# Ito's Formula (Standard and for Jump-Diffusion Proceses) Proof

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, levy-processes

I'm currently reading Cont & Tankov's "Financial Modelling With Jump Processes" and in proposition 8.14 they present Ito formula for jump-diffusion processes. There is no proof provided there. I am wondering if anyone could point me to the literature providing the proof. Additionally, if anyone knows a book providing a proof for regular Ito formula that would be good.

Many thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "jump-diffusion process"? A proof of Itô's formula for jump processes can be, for instance, found in the monographs by Protter and Ikeda & Watanabe on stochastic integration.

Comment: By a jump diffusion process I mean a stochastic process $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ defined by 
$$ X_t = \mu t + \sigma W_t + \sum_{k=1}^{N_t}Y_k, $$
where $W=(W_t)_{t\geq0}$ is standard Brownian motion, independent from $N$ (compound Poisson process) and $Y$ (i.i.d. jump variables), is called a \textit{jump-diffusion process} with drift $\mu$, volatility of diffusion $\sigma$, intensity $\lambda$, and jump size distribution $f_Y$.

Comment: If the jumps don't accumulate (as in your example with compound Poisson process), then you can write Ito formula in between jumps and adjust it accordingly e.g. $F(X(\tau_k)) - F(X(\tau_k-)) = F(X(\tau_k-)+Y_k) - F(X(\tau_k-))$ for the compound Poisson jump part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the book: D. Applebaum, *Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus*, 2nd Ed, Cambridge University Press, 2005. Th.4.4.7, p.251.